# Excel Convert Time with units

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

If I have a cell with time data formatted as `1m 11s`, how can I convert this to something Excel can understand?

Comment: What are the other combinations?  Could you provide more examples?

Comment: Yup, 
4w 3d 0h 0m 0s
12s
0s
4w 2d 23h 59m 59s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula will convert it to a time.  I made it as dynamic as I could:

```
=TIME(IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("h",A1)-MIN(SEARCH("h",A1),3)+1,MIN(SEARCH("h",A1),3)-1),0),IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("m",A1)-MIN(SEARCH("m",A1),3)+1,MIN(SEARCH("m",A1),3)-1),0),IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("s",A1)-MIN(SEARCH("s",A1),3)+1,MIN(SEARCH("s",A1),3)-1),0))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Nice answer. Can it be easily modified to copy with capitals (H, M, S) as well as lower case?

Comment: @DavidPostill yeah, I should have used search instead.  See update.

Comment: Thanks Scott! So there isn't any easy way to have excel interpret the cell as a time cell and format it as I wish? This formula works and I appreciate your time, i'd just like to know for future reference.

Comment: @michael.wang no, unfortunately Excel cannot think and reason, so everything must be programmed.  This is not one of the patterns that excel will currently see as a date/time, so we need to manipulate the text into a form that Excel can interpret.